# Is independence a transitive property?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

If the events $A$ and $B$ are independent and the events $B$ and $C$ are independent, does this necessarily mean events $A$ and $C$ are independent?

I used coin tosses to try to model this with $A = H$, $B = T$, and $C = H$ in separate fair tosses.

I get that they are independent, but am not sure if I am correct.

I also have problems determining if $B$ is independent to $A\cap C$ and also $A \cup C$.

Comment: Couldn't $A$ and $C$ be the same event? In that case they obviously wouldn't be independent.

Comment: If A and C are mutually exclusive? For example, 2 dies: A:first die=1, B:second die=1, C:first die=6. That is A and B, and B and C are independent. However, A and C are not...

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: That was not a question. I mean that generally this is not true...

Comment: so B would be independent of the union and intersect of A and C in the above example?

Comment: Yes, if two dies are independent

Comment: However, it is entirely possible to have $A,B$ independent, $B,C$ independent, and $A,C$ independent but at the same time $B$ and $A\cap C$ are dependent (and $B$ and $A\cup C$ also dependent).

Comment: so there is no concrete proof given the above conditions of A and B independent, B and C independent

Comment: Replace "no concrete proof" by "no concrete result".